# Comparing the rank of two matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-rank, projection-matrices

I came across this question in a study guide:

Let $A$ and $B$ be two real $5 \times  5$ matrices, such that $A^{2} = A$, $B^2 = B$, and $I - (A+B)$ is invertible. Prove that rank$(A)$ = rank$(B)$.

Any ideas on where to start? I know that for projection matrices,  $Range(P) = Kernel(I-P)$. Is it enough to say that for $x \in Range(A)$, $(I - (A + B))x = -Bx \in Range(B)$, and since $I - (A+B)$ is a bijection, the dimensions of the two ranges are the same? Thanks in advance.

Comment: That works as a proof for me.

Comment: Yes, it is ok. (We have an injective map from the image of $A$ to the image of $B$, so one inequality between the ranges, by symmetry also the other one.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note $I-(A+B)$ is invertible, hence when composed with another matrix $M$, the rank will not change. Now consider $(I-(A+B))A$ as well as $B(I-(A+B))$. What can you conclude along with the conditions of $A^2=A, B^2=B$?